# DotNetty connection reset by peer on second connection

Tags: c#

I've started a project using DotNetty but i'm struggling for making it work.

I can connect to my server one time but when i restart my test application i'm getting this exception telling me connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (This exception is received on client side not server side)

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
```

Here is the code I'm using to start the server

```
public class NetworkServer : INetworkServer
{
    private readonly ServerConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ClientSessionInitializer _clientSessionInitializer;

    private IChannel _channel;

    public NetworkServer(ServerConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger, ClientSessionInitializer clientSessionInitializer)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _clientSessionInitializer = clientSessionInitializer;
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var bossGroup = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup(1);
        var workerGroup = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup();

        try
        {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .Group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .Channel<TcpServerSocketChannel>()
                .ChildHandler(_clientSessionInitializer);

            _channel = await bootstrap.BindAsync(_configuration.Port);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("[NetworkServer] Exception on server start setup", ex);
        }
    }

    public async Task Stop()
    {
        if (_channel == null)
        {
            _logger.Warning("Can't stop NetworkServer, not yet started.");
            return;
        }

        await _channel.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

ClientSessionInitializer used in ServerBootstrap

```
public class ClientSessionInitializer : ChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IClientSessionFactory _clientSessionFactory;
    private readonly MessageToMessageEncoder<IPacket> _encoder;
    private readonly MessageToMessageDecoder<IByteBuffer> _decoder;

    public ClientSessionInitializer(ILogger logger, IClientSessionFactory clientSessionFactory, MessageToMessageEncoder<IPacket> encoder, MessageToMessageDecoder<IByteBuffer> decoder)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _clientSessionFactory = clientSessionFactory;
        _encoder = encoder;
        _decoder = decoder;
    }

    protected override void InitChannel(ISocketChannel channel)
    {
        IChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.Pipeline;
        ClientSession session = _clientSessionFactory.CreateClientSession(channel);

        pipeline.AddLast(_decoder);
        pipeline.AddLast(_encoder);
        pipeline.AddLast(session);

        _logger.Information($"Session with id {session.Id} created");
    }
}
```

ClientSession used in ClientSessionInitializer

```
public class ClientSession : NetworkClient, IClientSession
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public ClientSession(ILogger logger, IChannel channel) : base(logger, channel)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
    {
        Logger.Debug($"Packet received {message}");
    }

    public override void ChannelUnregistered(IChannelHandlerContext context)
    {
        Logger.Debug($"Session with id {Id} closed.");
        context.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Here is my NetworkClient class used by ClientSession

```
public class NetworkClient : ChannelHandlerAdapter, INetworkClient
{
    protected ILogger Logger { get; }
    protected IChannel Channel { get; }

    protected NetworkClient(ILogger logger, IChannel channel)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Channel = channel;
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Logger.Information("Disconnect");
        Channel.DisconnectAsync();
    }

    public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Fatal("NetworkClient exception", exception);
        context.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

And the code i'm using for my tests

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var socket = new TcpClient();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];

    socket.Connect("localhost", 4000);

    if (!socket.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't connect");
        return;
    }

    var stream = socket.GetStream();

    stream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("mysuperpacket"));
    int count = stream.Read(buffer);
    byte[] output = new byte[count];

    Array.Copy(buffer, output, count);

    string content = Encoding.Default.GetString(output);

    Console.WriteLine(content);
    socket.Close();
    socket.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks for you help, i've tested bunch of things but i can't found a way to fix this.